# MYSQL LAST_INSERT_ID not working as intended. How do I fix?

Tags: java, mysql, procedure

I wrote MySQL StoredProcedure to create and return new ID for each table value, however, it gets wrong value on last_insert_id() from MySQL WorkBench and Java application.

This procedure will be called from multiple sessions.

```
CALL `GET_NEW_ID`('test', @test);
select @test;
```

It gives me "141215000000" and this means last_insert_id() returns 0 all the time.
I see it correctly inserts new data into seq_data as supposed though.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GET_NEW_ID`(IN V_TABLE VARCHAR(10), OUT V_ID VARCHAR(12))
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO seq_data ( id, `name`, `stat_date`)
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id), 0)+1, V_TABLE, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d') FROM seq_data WHERE name = V_TABLE AND stat_date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d');
    SET V_ID = concat(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y%m%d'),LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 6, '0'));

END
```

Table looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `seq_data` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `stat_date` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`name`,`stat_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

My goal is like...

```
CALL `GET_NEW_ID`('test', @test);
select @test;
```

return 141215000001

```
CALL `GET_NEW_ID`('test', @test);
select @test;
```

return 141215000002

```
CALL `GET_NEW_ID`('hello', @test);
select @test;
```

return 141215000001

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id), LAST_INSERT_ID() returns a BIGINT (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value that was set for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by **the most recently executed INSERT statement to affect such a column**.

In your case, you are inserting the id, so an AUTO_INCREMENT value is not generated, thus LAST_INSERT_ID returns 0.

You may try something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GET_NEW_ID`(IN V_TABLE VARCHAR(10), OUT V_ID VARCHAR(12))
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO seq_data (`name`, `stat_date`)
    SELECT V_TABLE, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d') FROM seq_data WHERE name = V_TABLE AND stat_date = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d');
    SET V_ID = concat(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%y%m%d'),LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 6, '0'));

END
```

Comment: Thanks @Dondon for the answer. But I already tried that and the reason inserting id is to get a new id for a different column 'name'. For example, if I want to get a new id for table hello, then its id won't start from 1 since there's another id 1 for test table name.

Comment: Again, Thank you @Dodon, that explains why it's not working as I intended, I need to find a workaround to solve the problem.

Comment: @handicop You're doing it wrong. Generating a new ID yourself and *then* inserting it manually isn't the correct answer. It overlooks transactional requirements for a start. You shouldn't even *have* a `GET_NEW_ID()` procedure. It should just happen automatically as a side-effect of the `INSERT` in a table with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` key.

Comment: Hi @EJP, yes, I just had a chat with someone who knows about DB well, he was saying exactly the same thing you wrote here. Now I changed the table structure and removed GET_NEW_ID procedure. Thanks a lot!